# Create Template Field for n number of columns in Database at RunTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to develop a Web Tool which shows Grid View containing Data of a Table which is generated at run time. 
I want to create Filter functionality with Drop Down List on all the columns of GridView except 1 at run time.

For Now only Header Template is getting populated with Distinct Rows in Drop DownList but Complete Column Down is Empty. and GridView is getting Populated with same Columns again in the end of last Column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your problem.

Comment: I was able to populate Data but now I am facing Different Problem.